# Cannot access tomcat instance installed in EC2

Tags: tomcat, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-server

I have install tomcat 7 in an Ubuntu EC2 instance. It's up and running but I cannot access it using the public ip (54.213.225.148:8080). I have also setup the security groups as specified in the previous posts. But, still no luck.

[image: security groups setup]

Any help on this would be really appreciated.

Comment: Can you connect to it from the instance itself (`curl localhost:8080...`)?

Comment: Is the ec2 instance also running ubuntu? Did you open 8080 to tcp on Ubuntu Uncomplicated Firewall? https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UncomplicatedFirewall

Comment: @UriAgassi : localhost:8080 works fine. Issue is i cannot access it from the public ip

Comment: @jeremyjjbrown i tried sudo ufw allow ssh/tcp. but still the same issue

Comment: And the security group for your instance is `default`?

Comment: @UriAgassi yes. The security group is default. It seems that the port 8080 is not open in the server. I tried sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT. But still it shows as 8080 is not open

Comment: Is it amazon linux or ubuntu?

Comment: @jeremyjjbrown Its ubuntu..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure your [Ubuntu Uncomplicated Firewall](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/firewall.html) is controlling the traffic instead of iptables.

```
sudo ufw enable
```

Then [to configure it](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/firewall.html#firewall-ufw) to allow 8080.

```
sudo ufw allow 8080
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. One more thing to add is you will have to restart the server to effect the changes.

Comment: Your welcome. I assume you restarted after ufw enable but before opening 8080.

Comment: @jeremyjjbrown, I'm not able to ssh into the machine after this was done. Any suggestions?

Comment: Alibash did you allow port 22?

Comment: @jeremyjjbrown Should I restart the EC2 instance or just tomcat7 server (which is installed within EC2 instance)

Comment: @user3705478 I wouldn't use UFW in EC2 I would use AWS security groups instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should Add the port number to the firewall setting in the system also.

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```

where `8080` is the tomcat port number.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I have already tried this. But still the same result. :(

Comment: Try this   sudo 
service iptables stop

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 14.04 in EC2

```
#to save the rules you have created and to load them when the server starts.
sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent
sudo service iptables-persistent start

#the rule that explicitly accepts your current SSH connection
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
#block all incoming traffic, except for those: 22 for SSH and 80 for web traffic
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport ssh -j ACCEPT
#block the remaining traffic
sudo iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
#allow loopback access
sudo iptables -I INPUT 1 -i lo -j ACCEPT
#save changes
sudo /etc/init.d/iptables-persistent save

#allow port 8080
sudo iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
sudo /etc/init.d/iptables-persistent save
```

more on iptables on Ubuntu

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-using-ip-tables-on-ubuntu-12-04
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-using-iptables-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 0):

Just by enabling HTTP/HTTPS will not work. You need to enable TCP port too.

Also it need not be just public ip, you can access tomcat even if it is in your VPC using private IP address.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Server 2016

1. On AWS -> Security Group for EC2 enable:

   - Inbound Rules (All trafic - Anywhere)
   - Outbound Rules (All trafic - Anywhere)
2. On Remote EC2 open -> "Windows firewall with Anvanced Security" and open

   - Inbound (All ports)
   - Outbound (All ports)

Thats work for me.

PD: be care this configuration is very insecure.